# Module fs missed in sockjs library

Tags: angularjs, sockjs

I'm doing an app with Angular an TypeScript. One of my components is sockjs.js, as a dependency of stomp.js. During the execution, I have the next error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "fs"

In the library sockt.js there isone line, in the startins with: `fs= require('fs')`, which is causing the problem. Anyone can help me saying why it isn't finding that library?

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you trying to use the server side component (`sockjs-node`) in a browser? If so, you probably need [the client](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client).

Comment: Thank you @robertklep Now the problem is other, but I'm checking the documentation to see if it is something in my code.

Comment: I need the SockJS library @robertklep, because otherwise, when I use the stomp It doesn't recognize the SockJS object definition, this is the new mistake:
`ReferenceError: SockJS is not defined`

Comment: Have you read [this](http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/#alternative)? It points to the location of a version of `SockJS` that should work.

Comment: No @robertklep. But I'm using stomp with Angular, as I said (ng-stomp), so this is not according to my problem, because I open it so:
`ngstomp.connect('my_url', connectHeaders)
    .then( function(frame){
 ngstomp.subscribe('/data', function(payload){
             [...]
 });
});`
SockJS is only as dependency of ng-stomp and stomp.

Comment: So how about [this](https://github.com/beevelop/ng-stomp#add-standalone-version-dependencies-included-to-your-html-file)?